# Cardano-node over HTTP? Or as stack/cabal dependency?

Tags: cardano-cli, cardano-node

Is there a way to include cardano-node as a dependency in my project? (Stack dependency or cabal dependency). I tried and it keeps failing because not all dependencies can be built. Maybe I need to include it as a Nix dependency, using a Nix project?

I am trying to write code that can make use of some features of cardano-cli and cardano-node without having to be using files.

Alternatively, is there a web wrapper around cardano-node? (That would allow me to create transactions, submit, query utxos, etc..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `cabal` exclusively. You can include `cardano-node` as a dependency in the top level `cabal.project` file using something like [what db-sync does](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/blob/master/cabal.project#L159-L171). This may require that you add some of the other `source-repository-package` s that `db-sync` uses.

> Alternatively, is there a web wrapper around cardano-node? (That would allow me to create transactions, submit, query utxos, etc..)

That sounds like part of the feature set of `cardano-db-sync` and the rest seems to be `cardano-tx-submit-api`.